# Two ways of calling default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following code:

```
struct B
{
 //B() {}
 int x;
 int y;
};

void print(const B &b) 
{
 std::cout<<"x:"<<b.x<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"y:"<<b.y<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"--------"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
 B b1 = B(); //init1
 B b2; //init2

 print(b1);
 print(b2);

 return 0;
}
```

When I start program (vs2008, debug) I have the following output:

```
x:0
y:0
--------
x:-858993460
y:-858993460
--------
```

As you can see b1.x and b1.y have 0 value. why? What's difference between init1 and init2?

When I uncomment B constructor I have the following output:

```
x:-858993460
y:-858993460
--------
x:-858993460
y:-858993460
--------
```

Can somebody explain the reason of this behaviour?
Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default constructor for POD types fills it with zeros. When you explicitly define your own constructor you are not initialize `x` and `y` and you'll get random values (in VS debug they are filled with exact values, but in release they will be random).

It is according to C++03 Standard 8.5/5:

> <...>To *value-initialize* an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   —  otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized**.

`B()` is a value-initialization of temporary which will be used in copy-initialization of `b1`.

In `B b2` there is no initializer specified for an object, so according to C++03 Standard 8.5/9:

> **If no initializer is specified for an object**, and the object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the object shall be default-initialized; if the object is of const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a user-declared default constructor.  **Otherwise, if no initializer is specified for a non-static object, the object and its subobjects, if any, have an indeterminate initial value**; if the object or any of its subobjects are of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed.

To get zeros for `b2` you could write `B b2 = {};`.

Comment: How does this explain the different results for `b1` and `b2`?

Comment: And the last case for "default-initialize" should be "otherwise, no initialization is performed." This is the crucial difference here.

Comment: @sth: No, default-initalize must zero-initialize other objects, the crucial point is that POD-types with automatic storage duration without an explicit initializer aren't even default-initialized.

Comment: @Charles: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2914.pdf says in 8.5/6 that no initialization is performed. That's the C++0x draft, so maybe it changed there, but I would be very surprised.

Comment: VS2008 is a compile for the ISO 14882:2003 version of C++, so I think that this is the version of the standard that we should be looking at, not a draft for the next version.

Comment: @sth, added explanation of different results for `b1` and `b2`.

Comment: isn't it just the value of whatever was in the relevant memory location last, not a random value? it's uninitialised, so it just uses whatever's already there !

Comment: @Ed Woodcock, value is undefined by C++ Standard and since its location is random due to stack randomization (and undefined by C++ Standard), I call it random.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to be clear that it wasn't in fact random, although it may appear to be, otherwise we'd probably have some clever sod trying to make a random number generator based on undefined values :D Random != Undefined

Answer (score 5):

In both cases, this statement defines b1 and *copy-intializes* it from a *value-initialized* temporary `B` object.

```
B b1 = B();
```

When `B` doesn't have a user-declared constructor, *value-initializing* causes call of `B`'s members to be *value-initalized*, and for simple types, such as `int`, this means *zero-initializing*.

When `B` does have a user-declared constructor, *value-initializing* tries to call the default constructor. If the members `x` and `y` are not listed in the constructor initializer list, then they are left uninitialized.

```
B b2;
```

In functions, local objects of POD-type without an initializer are left uninitialized. When you don't define a constructor for `B`, it is a POD-class so this applies and the values of `b2.x` and `b2.y` have indeterminate values.

If the object is of non-POD class type, then it is *default-initialized*, but if this calls a constructor which leaves its members uninitialized then this makes no difference.

Comment: Do you mean that in the first case both copy and default constructors are called?

Comment: Nominally, yes, but the compiler is allowed to optimize out the copy. In this case it might directly _value-initialize_ `b1`. Whatever the compiler chooses to do, the observable effect (to the program) must be the same.

Answer (score 3):

This is value-initialization versus no initialization. If you write

```
B b1 = B();
```

you get copy-initialization with a "value-initialized" temporary -- B(). Value-initialization of class-type objects invokes a user-defined constructor (if existant) or otherwise value-initializes the members. Value-initialization of scalar type objects is equivalent to zero-initialization. When you declare your own constructor that doesn't do anything, your scalar members are not initialized.

```
B b1;
```

is a default-initialization or no initialization at all (depending on B).

The exact initialization rules are rather complicated. See C++ standard section 8.5 "Initializers".

Answer (score 2):

The O's are explained by Kirill

The other value:-858993460 is 0xCCCCCCCC, which is the default value for uninitialized stack memory in VC's debug builds.

Uninitialized *heap* memory defaults to 0xCDCDCDCD. And of course, in release builds, the default contents is random.

Now, I have to admit that I didn't know it's legal to call a c'tor directly as you do in your example! And I would have sweared that this is illegal...

Comment: nitpicking: 0xCC is the default value for uninitialized **stack** memory in VC debug build. Uninitialized **heap** memory will contain 0xCD

Answer (score 0):

i tried on vc6 and Visual Studio 2005 i am getting below result in both:Could you please post disassemble code generated , Like below i have posted disassemble code for 2005

x:-858993460

y:-858993460

---

x:-858993460

y:-858993460

---

```
 B b1 = B(); //init1
0043DEDE  lea         ecx,[b1] 
0043DEE1  call        B::B (43ADD9h) 
 B b2; //init2
0043DEE6  lea         ecx,[b2] 
0043DEE9  call        B::B (43ADD9h) 

 print(b1);
0043DEEE  lea         eax,[b1] 
0043DEF1  push        eax  
0043DEF2  call        print (43A302h) 
0043DEF7  add         esp,4 
 print(b2);
0043DEFA  lea         eax,[b2] 
0043DEFD  push        eax  
0043DEFE  call        print (43A302h) 
0043DF03  add         esp,4
```

Comment: So, what's the reason of the difference? Assignment operators are out of the topic as they are not called. Destructors are also out of the topic. There is a lot of text in your post, but no clear answer.

Comment: @ Alex , thanks for comment, I assumed that opeator= was called, But after your comment i checked that it is not called at all, Let me do some testing , will reply soon :)